# Kafka cluster deploy in the cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, devops

I want to create and deploy Kafka cluster for data pipeline.
What is the prefer way to deploy it in the cloud , VMs or Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka can run either way. However, if this is the question you are asking, then you might want to question if you really want to manage your own Kafka cluster in the cloud. Why not use an existing Kafka as a service offering?

Comment: Hi @dawsaw and thx for your answer . We work with Azure and we have a lots of credits from them so it is all about the cost . In addition we want the ability of costumization

Comment: In that case, you can go with whatever technology you are comfortable with. There are prebuilt docker images out there if you want to go there container route. Just remember Kafka brokers are stateful so you need persistent storage no matter your deployment strategy.